# bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: reactjs

please solution the problem
'Messaging: We are unable to register the default s…t. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).'

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/Scripts/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
      .then(function(registration) {
        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
      });
    }

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "764889199739",
  })

const initMessaging = firebase.messaging()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.